# Grounding Neutral Off Grid Solar

Tags: ground, inverter, grounding, solar-energy, ground-loop

Is it recommended to ground the neutral line in an off grid solar system?

A nonisolated inverter would be by definition wired this way, right?

I believe that in home electrical systems neutral is connected to ground in one location. There is a ground bus and a neutral bus and they are linked in one location near the main home supply and the earth connection.

As I understand it when grounding the neutral line,

- If there is an earth fault on the neutral line nothing happens
- If there is an earth fault on the live line the inverter circuit breaker will trip. (if no other protection trips first)

If you do not ground the neutral line a GND fault will either ground the neutral line or the live line. I believe the disadvantage being that if the live line is grounded it is confusing for future problems unless there is an indication of the fault.

In a home system is there more danger because of the higher voltage transmission lines?

Would there be a difference if there was or was not a GFDI (Ground Fault Protector)?

[REF-1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271348/what-are-the-adavantages-of-neutral-vs-isolated-grounding)
[REF-2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120940/why-are-the-ground-and-neutral-bonded-in-my-panel)

Comment: I think you need to state your geographic location, electrical codes vary. But your best bet is to follow the installation instructions supplied by your inverter mfg - or consult with a local professional installer.

Comment: I guess I am looking for best practice, not necessarily code based. Or for instance why would an inverter manufacturer say to GND neutral? Because they are in a country where thats what it says in the code, because it protects against lightning strikes better, or because of the topology of their inverter?

Comment: What would you do if the Internet's concensus of best practice contradicted your country's legal code?

Comment: Well I would petition my local government, and if that didn't work I would run for office. If that didn't work I would immediately concede to my oppressive regime. No but, this is more theoretical, I want to know if I am missing anything. Right now I would think that grounding neutral makes more sense, especially for a more constricting code but is there a protection factor I am missing. For instance maybe an isolated system has less chance for shock because you have to be touching both leads.